# MaxLength of TEdit does not work on Android with DELPHI XE7 (update 1)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, maxlength, delphi-xe7

Does anyone know why does not work MaxLength of TEdit on Android with DELPHI XE7 (update 1)?

Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you set it at run-time on form creation, `Edit1.MaxLength := xxx`, does it work then? Note that this property only affects keyboard input.

Comment: I try it in run-time but it does not work. :(

Comment: Same problem is with TMemo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some problem in DELPHI XE7 update 1 (see my report [QC 129171](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=129171))

You can overcam it with this little code (example for MaxLength = 5):

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Typing(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Length(Edit1.Text) > 5 then
    Edit1.Text:= Edit1.Text.Substring(0, 5);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug I have also filed. Fortunately, the error was corrected in the next version.